# Posting file with form just makes PHP script hang when enctype set

Tags: php, forms, post, file-upload, enctype

My form with the method of POST for uploading a file only makes the receiving script hang (or it doesn't load properly), when `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data`. In Safari it takes a couple of minutes before the script collapses (gives up), but in Chrome it goes down right away. By *down* I mean that the user ist taken to the root of the site (`/`).

No errors to be found in the error log.

I've managed to make the form function without enctype and/or a file input, but then naturally, no file is posted.

It is a WAMP server with PHP7. Ini settings have all been carefully checked to be big enough.

The scripts worked until a couple of weeks ago, but the IT department cannot point to any specific updates that might be the cause.

```html
<form name="fileupload" action="fileReceive.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ahiddenvalue" value="The hidden value">
    <input type="file" name="upfile" id="fileToUpload" accept=".pdf, application/pdf">
    <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

File receiving script, fileReceive.php:

```php
exit("<pre>".print_r($_REQUEST)."\n".print_r($_FILES)."</pre>");
```

The loading bar in the address field of the browser just gets started, and hangs in Safari till about two minutes. No message about `max-execution_time` in the error log.

Comment: _“By down I mean that the user ist taken to the root of the site (/)”_ - then some explicit redirect to that root URL must be happening somewhere in your system, browsers don’t change the location willy-nilly on their own.

Comment: `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` - whatever you were hoping to achieve with this, I am sure you simply _won’t_ …

Comment: Yes, why should I suddenly become able to change some global - I don’t know where I got that from, pretty silly, and I have removed it. And I’ll check that url redirect on the server. I really wonder why it only happens when multipart/form-data comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: An url rewrite was set up un Apache with only lowercase file suffixes. When trying to fetch a file with uppercase file suffix, the script that was 'url rewritten' to, did not catch the file and just stopped everything by displaying the top page of the site.